# How to add page URL in HTML mailto: subject and body.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, mailto

How to add page URL in HTML mailto: subject and body.

Even some dynamic variable values need to be added.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code? Something you tried? Please, be more specific on your question and try to provide some examples!

Comment: What do you want exaclty? The mailto command expects an email adress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mailto in the url as :-

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">
```

It contains the recipients address and the subject... I hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
        <body>

         <p>
          This is an email link:
         <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">
                    Send Mail</a>
                   </p>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Note: Spaces between words should be replaced by %20 to ensure that                                  the browser will display the text properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to add a subject and body message. I find it works OK without `%20` between each word, but it's probably safer to use it. So you can either try this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@mysite.com?subject=Hi there&amp;body=This is my body message">Email Us</a>
```

or this

```
<a href="mailto:email@mysite.com?subject=Hi%20there&amp;body=This%20is%20my%20body%20 message">Email Us</a>
```

Note that I used `&amp;` rather than `&`, as just an `&` tends to be disliked in URLs. (It doesn't validate, anyhow.)